# How do I get all transaction data from Polygon API?

Tags: contract-design, polygon, explorer-api, transfers-api

Im trying to get all transaction data from a contract on Polygon. I know I need to use the API from Polygon,but i don't know the correct syntax to call.

Thnx in Advance!
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=%CONTRACT%&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=%APIKEY%
```

For further documentation check the API of Polygon. They have a nice documentation.